# Can someone translate this book title for me?

Tags: перевод

I was wondering if someone could translate this book title and also include the title in russian? I'm attempting to reference it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are not a bulky translation service here. 
You can use Google or something to translate textes.

English - > ***Functions of a one variable.*** 
Russian - > ***Функции одного переменного.***